# mysql replication with compression

Tags: mysql, compression, replication

I'd like to set use mysql replication with compression.

The master is a windows machine with mysql 5.5
The slave is on Linux (redhat) with mysql 5.0.

The replication works.

I tried to turn on compression with

set global slave_compressed_protocol=1;

on the slave

set global slave_compressed_protocol=1;

on the master.

But: I DO NOT see any improvement in the ability of the slave to keep up with the master.

Any ideas, what might be wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you sure compression isn't working? Maybe it is working, and just isn't helping enough.

Comment: That's a possibility. BTW, any ideas what good mysql replication monitors are? I am trying mysql monk now. Any others?

Comment: Another question in this context then: is there a way to skip ahead with the replication, i.e. stop the slave, skip ahead and then start replication again? Maybe I don't care about the old data and only want the most recent ones.

Comment: Don't know if you can do that, but if your slave is way behind, you can always resync from the current time. Dump the master db (and keep track of the log num, position at that time), then reload it into the slave and set the log num and time.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the network bandwidth in use from point to point.  Maybe use Wireshark to monitor.

Then I would look at the disk IO on the slave machine.  Slave IO isn't as fast as normal IO

I would install the pt-diskstats on the slave machine to get an idea about the IO load on the slave.  http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-diskstats.html

You have to find where the bottleneck is.  If it is a disk bottleneck, then compression won't help.

I'm also rather nervous about you having different versions.  I've always been taught that slave machine version should be newer or the same as the master.  In other words,  Replicating to an older slave is bad.

Answer (score 0):

slave_compressed_protocol=1 will only compress time to transfer data across network, which is small portion of over all time spent, but wont help on single-thread slave execution thread (vs Master has multi-threads )